# play framework wizard dynamic fields

Tags: forms, playframework, playframework-2.0, wizard

I am trying to follow the Wizard pattern in Forms sample provided with Play (https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/forms/app/views/wizard/form1.scala.html).

This approach looks okay when the number of fields are static. But, how do I deal with this when the fields are dynamic. e.g. if there are going to be multiple profiles that a user can create in step2, how do I represent it on this page?

Also, does it mean that every page of my wizard will have to know about all the controls on rest of the pages, and make those hidden? There must be a better approach to solve this problem. Can you pls help?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem while working with wizards. I solved it by decoupling my DB models from UI models. e.g. at DB level, I have one model that represents a whole car. At UI layer, I created multiple models that represent parts of the car e.g. wheels, seats, doors etc.

In the UI wizard, I use the UI models. So, at any given step my wizard step only needs to know about the parts that it operates on. I can apply the validation constraints such as @required etc. on these models. If form validation on part succeeds, I would update the DB model with that information. HTH.